# Rails, jquery problem

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a link to destroy action, after press the link I delete a div that contains element in my view, I make it with prototype and it works fine, but now I need to use jquery instead prototype, I don't change my code but it doesnot work now.

In view: `<%= link_to "delete", p, :method=> :delete, :remote=> true %>`
and js.erb: `$("#delete_row_id_#{@product.id.to_s}).remove();`

Then I press the link rails redirect me on details page, seems like :method=> :delete and :remote=> true doesn't work with jquery. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

File `public/javascripts/rails.js` exist?

Try `rails generate jquery:install #--ui to enable jQuery UI`

Comment: yes, rail.js exist, I put manualy jquery and rails.js in my js folder

Comment: I try to install jquery like a gem and the :remote and :method works now but the code in js.erb doesn't execute

Comment: Please show me the server's response when click on the link. Is send controller content-type application/javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the jquery specific rails.js? You can find it here:
https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs